# Remove brackets from a single citation

Tags: citing, natbib, chicago-style, mdpi

I'm writing a manuscript using `mdpi` document class. The document class and `.bst` file for the citations is provided by [MDPI Instructions for Authors](http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex). The citation style is `chicago2.bst`. Unfortunately I had to use an apud citation, for this I wrote:

```
\citep[\textit{apud} \citep{Key2}]{Key1}
```

And I got something like:

> [1, *apud* [2]]

How can I get a citation like:

> [1 *apud* 2]

or

> [1, *apud* 2]

withouth compromissing the original files porvided by the journal?

Comment: For the second solution, try `\citep[\textit{apud} \cite{Key2}]{Key1}`?

Comment: @Bernard it didn't work :(

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

I founded the solution.

Simply use the command `\citenum{Key}`

```
\citep[\textit{apud} \citenum{Key2}]{Key1}
```

then I got

> [1, *apud* 2]

Comment: I suppose you're using `natbib`?

Comment: @Bernard yes, the document class already has loaded natbib