# Remove brackets from a single citation (without natbib)

Tags: bibliographies, citing

How to remove brackets around a specific citation in the text:

```
See [1] and [2], but 3 is what I need, and [4] is ok.
```

Here, what command would give `3` and not `[3]` as `\cite` gives? For the other citations in the same document, brackets like `[1]` are OK.

This is not a duplicate of "[Remove brackets from a single citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380181/remove-brackets-from-a-single-citation)" because the command `\citenum` recommended there needs an additional package (probably `natbib`).

My motivation is citing two papers, each with page numbers. It seems it is impossible using normal citing commands:

```
See [1, p 12] and [2, p 23], but [3, p 34; 5, p 45] is what I need, and [4, p 56] is ok
```

so I expect to simulate it with commands like

```
See \cite[p 12]{A} and \cite[p 23]{B}, 
but [\citeNoBrackets[p 34]{C}; \citeNoBrackets[p 45]{E}] is what I need, 
and \cite[p 56]{D} is ok.
```

For this, I need a command like `\citeNoBrackets` that behaves as `\cite` but does not add brackets. How do I do it?

Note: `\def\@biblabel#1{#1}` does just the opposite: it changes the References list, but does not change how citations appear in the text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    See \cite[p 12]{A} and \cite[p 23]{B}, 
    but [\cite[p 34]{C}; \cite[p 45]{E}] is what I need, 
    and \cite[p 56]{D} is ok.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

`test.bib`:

```
@Article{A, author = {A}, title = {A}, journal = {A}, year = {A}}
@Article{B, author = {B}, title = {B}, journal = {B}, year = {B}}
@Article{C, author = {C}, title = {C}, journal = {C}, year = {C}}
@Article{D, author = {D}, title = {D}, journal = {D}, year = {D}}
@Article{E, author = {E}, title = {E}, journal = {E}, year = {E}}
```

which produces

```
See [1, p 12] and [2, p 23], but [[3, p 34]; [5, p 45]] is what I need, and [4, p 56] is ok.
```

with unwanted double brackets.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `natbib`? It is very widely used and accepted by publishers.

Comment: natbib was created to do what you want. Where is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure if it will not alter a given style. In addition, I cannot get it working with the particular style I have to use, `svjour3.cls`.

Comment: A minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem would help a lot.

Comment: The `svjour3.cls` *has* a `natbib` option, so it's definitely compatible with `natbib`. You're asking people to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Alan is right. The template that comes with that class has `\DeclareOption{natbib}{\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{natbib}` - so you just start your document with `\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3}`. This loads the natbib package, and you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, but in my case it gives an error `Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` I do not see how to give it an option `[numbers]`. (How to debug this would be another question.) But in any case, I thought there should be a trivial way to get rid of the brackets without more packages.

Comment: In my MWE, just changing `\documentclass{article}` for `\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3}` here produces this error. Maybe it's a problem of configuration of my computer, not sure.

Comment: It works if I add `\usepackage{natbib}` and copy all its parameters from the class, but this is hacking, not an intended use of the class.

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem here. Load the `svjour3` class with the `natbib` option, add `\setcitestyle{numbers,square}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to your preamble. Then use regular `natbib` commands. If that doesn't work, edit your question with a minimal example *showing this* and then perhaps we can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, `\setcitestyle{numbers}` solved the `svjour3` problem, thank you! But even with this, I would be interested (for the future, or for other readers) to know the answer to the original question, if somebody wants to provide it.

Comment: The answer would just copy the code from natbib. It was already done. of course one could argue that to avoid natbib, one could just as well copy tge relevant code from the more modern biblatex package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lightly tested.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts,},
    Title = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Year = {1984}}

@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965}}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifnobrackets
\renewcommand\@cite[2]{\ifnobrackets\else[\fi{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}\ifnobrackets\else]\fi\nobracketsfalse}
\newcommand\nbcite{\nobracketstrue\cite}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
[\nbcite[p.4]{Knuth1984texbook} and \nbcite[p.5]{Chomsky1965}] show that ...
\cite[p.4]{Knuth1984texbook} and \cite[p.5]{Chomsky1965} show that ...
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I wonder whether the same effect cannot be achieved by just removing the first and last character from the result of `\cite`.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh I've simplified the code.