# How to explicitly refer to citation with "ref. N" without square brackets / remove brackets in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have set a bibliography style (`nature`) such that `\cite{key1}` produces "[1]" in the text. Given two `.bib`-entries with keys `key1` and `key2`, I want to write

> Statement A is true [1]. Therefore, following the discussion in ref. 2, statement B is also true.

It is preferred to avoid the square brackets of "... in ref. [2], ..." that would appear with the naive `... in ref. \cite{key2}, ...`. What is a good way to write ref. 2 without square brackets?

I am using the `biblatex` package, so any solution using `natbib`'s `\citenum` command seems incompatible. And the solution provided in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384790/remove-brackets-from-a-single-citation-without-natbib) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ingredients for a command like this are available, we just have to put them together.

We define a new command `\refcite` based on the default definition of `\cite`. But in the precode we inject some code that prints "ref." or "refs." (depending on the number of citation as stored in `citetotal`).

You can find the original definition of `\cite` as used by `nature.cbx` in [`numeric-comp.cbx` (ll. 209-216 in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx#L209).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{ref}
\NewBibliographyString{refs}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  ref  = {ref\adddot},
  refs = {refs\adddot},
}

\newbibmacro{cite:intro:ref}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{citetotal}}{1}
    {\bibstring{refs}}
    {\bibstring{ref}}%
  \printunit{\addnbspace}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\refcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:intro:ref}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
\newrobustcmd*{\Refcite}{\bibsentence\refcite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \refcite{sigfridsson}

Lorem \refcite{nussbaum}

Lorem \refcite{nussbaum,geer}

\Refcite{sigfridsson}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ref. 1//Lorem ref. 2//Lorem refs. 2, 3//Ref. 1//Lorem 1]

---

If you just want a naked citation without any brackets, you can define something like

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\barecite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Again, this definition is based on `\cite`, but it omits the wrapper `[\mkbibbrackets]`.